# Correct answer button green

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a quiz, and I am trying to turn my answer button green when correct and when incorrect red and then save this information and move onto the next question. However the code at the moment is not working. This is my JavaScript code:

```
let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex;

const setNextQuestion = () => {
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]);
}

const showQuestion = (gameData) => {
    questionElement.innerText = gameData.question;
    let answersBlock = '';
    gameData.answer.forEach((answer, index) => {
        const answerButton = `
            <div class="answers-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <button class="btn answer-button" id="answersbutton-${index + 1}" onclick="selectAnswer()">
                    ${answer.text}
                </button>
            </div>
        `;
        answersBlock += answerButton;
    });
    answerButtonsElement.innerHTML = answersBlock;
}

const selectAnswer = (e) => {
    const selectedButton = e.target;
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
    setStatusClass(document.body, correct);
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
        setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct);
    })
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    clearStatusClass(element);
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('wrong');
    }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct');
    element.classList.remove('wrong');
}


const gameData = [
    {
        question: 'What is the smallest country in the world?',
        answer: [
            { text: 'Vatican City', correct: true },
            { text: 'Malta', correct: false },
            { text: 'Italy', correct: false },
            { text: 'Monaco', correct: false }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: What isn't working? Have you debugged it all using the development tools in your browser? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Don't store the answer result into `data-*` attributes. Store them in your gameData instead.

Comment: Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: Yes this is an error: script.js:131 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
    at selectAnswer (script.js:131:30)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the event as a parameter in `onclick` because you are using the event in HTML and calling it directly.

```js
const answerButton = `
            <div class="answers-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <button class="btn answer-button" id="answersbutton-${index + 1}" onclick="selectAnswer(event)">
                    ${answer.text}
                </button>
            </div>
        `;
```

And get it as `event.target` in `selectAnswer` function.

```js
function selectAnswer(event) {
  console.log("Button", event.target)
}
```